# Place a submit button inside of a table cell

Tags: php, mysql, button, html-table

I am trying to put a button in my table after retrieve data from database, but I got a problem in creating the button.

Here is my code to create the button:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    Print "<tr>"; 
    Print "<td><input type="submit" name="asc_sort" value-"Submit">sort</input></td>";
    Print "<td>high:</td> <td>".$row['invention_title'] . "</td>"; 
    Print "<td>lower:</td> <td>".$row['invention-title'] . " </td></tr>"; 
}
Print "</table>";
```

but I got an error

> syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\fak_ict1999\showDB.php on line 35

and line 35 is

```
 Print "<td><input type="submit" name="asc_sort" value-"Submit">sort</input></td>";
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Miss placed quotes. Escape the quotes with `\\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change enclosing quote marks to apostropes in the second printed line:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    Print "<tr>"; 
    Print '<td><input type="submit" name="asc_sort" value="Submit">sort</input></td>';
    Print "<td>high:</td> <td>".$row['invention_title'] . "</td>"; 
    Print "<td>lower:</td> <td>".$row['invention-title'] . " </td></tr>"; 
}
Print "</table>";
```

Or escape inner quotes:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    Print "<tr>"; 
    Print "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"asc_sort\" value=\"Submit\">sort</input></td>";
    Print "<td>high:</td> <td>".$row['invention_title'] . "</td>"; 
    Print "<td>lower:</td> <td>".$row['invention-title'] . " </td></tr>"; 
}
Print "</table>";
```

Also, watch out for the mistake you made at the Submit button, should be `=` instead of `-`

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the quotes inside your print statement, like,

```
print "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"asc_sort\" value=\"Submit\">sort</input></td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the type of quotes you're using on line 35 or escape the double qoutes.

```
Print '<td><input type="submit" name="asc_sort" value-"Submit">sort</input></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape `"` by `\"` inside `"`. Or you could use `'` to quote the string then use `"` inside.

Answer (score 0):

**First:** Learn about [tokens](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) as it will give you insight in the future, about what causes syntax errors, and how you can handle them by yourself, instead of asking here. Second:

Change this

```
"<td><input type="submit" name="asc_sort" value-"Submit">sort</input></td>";
```

to this

```
"<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"asc_sort\" value=\"Submit\">sort</input></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line should read like `print "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"asc_sort\" value=\"Submit\">sort</input></td>";`

Comment: Plus you wrote `value-"Submit"` and it wasn't `-` but `=`. Now, it should be fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change while loop to this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    Print "<tr>"; 
    Print "<td><input type='submit' name='asc_sort' value='Submit'>sort</input></td>";
    Print "<td>high:</td> <td>".$row['invention_title'] . "</td>"; 
    Print "<td>lower:</td> <td>".$row['invention-title'] . " </td></tr>"; 
}
Print "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your double quotes or use single quotes. your line should read:

```
Print '<td><input type="submit" name="asc_sort" value="Submit">sort</input></td>';
```

This is an example of where code highlighting is really helpful. Look at your example, and you can see that the word 'submit' is in black while the rest of the line is red. thats because PHP thinks it isn't part of the string you are printing.

Answer (score 0):

value should have an = not -, as also mentioned try double quotes on the outside and single inside.

```
value="Submit"
```